# PHP Sha-256 not giving result as required by ogone

Tags: php, hash

I have a sting to hash with sha-256

```
string= ACCEPTURL=http://atifali.com/pn/index.php?ic=paymentdone&id=E0I0m21E20n2OddgqckVb$Y8U027S7$1+++HASHKEY+++AMOUNT=7600+++HASHKEY+++BGCOLOR=#f1f3f2+++HASHKEY+++BUTTONBGCOLOR=#2f85c4+++HASHKEY+++BUTTONTXTCOLOR=#FFFFFF+++HASHKEY+++CANCELURL=http://atifali.com/pn/?ic=payment+++HASHKEY+++CN=WAQAS KHAN+++HASHKEY+++CURRENCY=GBP+++HASHKEY+++DECLINEURL=http://atifali.com/pn/?ic=payment+++HASHKEY+++EXCEPTIONURL=http://atifali.com/pn/?ic=payment+++HASHKEY+++HOMEURL=http://atifali.com/pn/+++HASHKEY+++LANGUAGE=en_us+++HASHKEY+++ORDERID=sterlingpharma1234+++HASHKEY+++PSPID=sterlingpharma+++HASHKEY+++TXTCOLOR=#2f85c4+++HASHKEY+++
```

expected result by ogone is:

```
979600BF6E1789CDD18B0F5669C7F2A958E88736B4C23BE2FC0B47FEF25496AF
```

but I'm having the result as:

```
267B4AD7CF0ACD3E2111ADD33CAFDD91EE1C4ACAEEF946C846D92A220283D4D9
```

by using:

```
strtoupper(hash('sha256',$stringToHash))
```

Comment: I'm sure ogone will give you an example string including all parameters and the `SHA-256` hash it resulted in. Use that exact string in your hash and you'll see that it's correct.

Comment: yes, ogone sent me the example but I've tried the same string in php function and on the gone SHA Test Page calculator https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/testsha.asp but result does not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious and give it a go. I checked [the manual on page 14](https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/Ogone_e-Com-BAS_EN.pdf) and found some input string.

I used [your code on the value](http://codepad.org/SFR2HTJb) and the result was

```
E019359BAA3456AE5A986B6AABD22CF1B3E09438739E97F17A7F61DF5A11B30F
```

Which is exactly the same as I get on [SHA Test Page](https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/testsha.asp) from ogone.

So the hash function is correct. I guess you misformed the actual string. Best way to test is with an easy string like 'test'.

Comment: Thanks, I got the right result by removing the given below part from string,BGCOLOR=#f1f3f2+++HASHKEY+++BUTTONBGCOLOR=#2f85c4+++HASHKEY+++BUTTONTXTCOLOR=#FFFFFF+++HASHKEY+++

Comment: but did not understand why these values are making difference in conversion

Comment: They dont. Probably why you had to remove them

Comment: that were optional fields. Actully we have to hash the strings that we are posting in request I also skipped that fields from request.